# Handling Apple events from console app on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, appleevents

Please give me some hints about how to work and, more practically, handle Apple events from raw console application written in C++ on Mac. I know that there is huge infrastructure for this purpose in Cocoa but as I think this is only a wrapper. 
May be it's impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is C API for it:

http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Open_Scripti_Architecture/Reference/reference.html

and

http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Apple_Event_Manager/Reference/reference.html

Overview:

http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/intro_aepg/intro_aepg.html

But as you can see that Apple considers this as legacy nowadays, so for a new project, using the Objective-C APIs might be the better choice.